# Biblatex bibilographic data in the main file

Tags: biblatex

I have been using Bibtex.  When I send a source file to a journal I always put the bbl file into it.  I am looking into Biblatex and it looks like that will not work. Is there a way to get bibliographic data into the main LaTeX file with Biblatex, or do you have to send separate files? Would the answer change if I used Biber with it?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be quite the answer you wanted, but you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{aFileName.bib}
   <contents of bibliography file>
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{aFileName.bib}

\begin{document}
   <contents of document>
\end{document}
```

The file `aFileName.bib` will be created during compilation and left in the working folder.

There may be other methods for solving this though.