# biblatex insert list of references in the source file

Tags: biblatex

Simple question, I think.  A journal is asking me to submit the LaTeX source file.  I used BibLaTeX for the list of references.  I would now like to include the formatted list of references in the source file, so that I don't have to submit the bib files along with the tex file.  With BibTeX, I could simply copypaste the bbl file into the tex file, if I remember correctly.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Not really. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42359/277964

Comment: That can be rather dangerous, the output from biber **has** to match the biblatex version being used. So you can end up with the journal having one version of biblatex and you have a newer.

Comment: Generally for journals only use `biblatex` if you know the journal supports it, otherwise use `bibtex`

Comment: Herbert has posted a kind of workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/277964). But this IMHO has the disadvantage, that it can fail easily, if another `biblatex` version is used. I would therefore advise against it myself.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried some of the suggestions, but none of them worked.  I was not aware of this problem.  It's a good reason to go back to BibTeX.